# Trying to draw on a user loaded bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-canvas, draw

I'm trying to draw on a user loaded bitmap. This is in `onCreate`.

```
imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);

Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Next code is when the user press a button to get the bitmap and after the bitmap is successfully retrieved. It is at the end of 
"`onActivityResult`"

```
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

I'm able to draw on the blank bitmap that is made during `onCreate`, but when the user loads the new bitmap and try to draw it doesn't show. The new bitmap is loaded though.

I tired doing this too

```
canvas = new Canvas(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

then it gave me error.

Anyone know if i'm doing something wrong?

EDIT:THis is the log file:

```
10-25 03:19:31.409: W/System.err(1971): java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor
10-25 03:19:31.409: W/System.err(1971):     at com.example.milestone2.Draw.onActivityResult(Draw.java:148)
10-25 03:19:31.409: W/System.err(1971):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
10-25 03:19:31.409: W/System.err(1971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
10-25 03:19:31.409: W/System.err(1971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
10-25 03:19:31.409: W/System.err(1971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-25 03:19:31.419: W/System.err(1971):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
10-25 03:19:31.419: W/System.err(1971):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-25 03:19:31.419: W/System.err(1971):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-25 03:19:31.428: W/System.err(1971):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-25 03:19:31.428: W/System.err(1971):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 03:19:31.428: W/System.err(1971):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-25 03:19:31.428: W/System.err(1971):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-25 03:19:31.428: W/System.err(1971):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-25 03:19:31.428: W/System.err(1971):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-25 03:19:31.438: W/System.err(1971): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor
10-25 03:19:31.448: W/System.err(1971):     at android.graphics.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:127)
10-25 03:19:31.469: W/System.err(1971):     at com.example.milestone2.Draw.onActivityResult(Draw.java:141)
10-25 03:19:31.469: W/System.err(1971):     ... 13 more
10-25 03:19:31.588: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

Comment: Can you see the bitmap in the `imageView` after you get the result? What error do you get?

Comment: Yep, it loads. I just can't draw on it. There's no crash.

But when i tired 
   canvas = new Canvas(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

I get this

Comment: com.example.milestone2.Draw.onActivityResult(Draw.java:139)
10-25 02:59:05.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5293)
10-25 02:59:05.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
10-25 02:59:05.829: E/AndroidRuntime(1826):  ... 11 more

Comment: Sorry but I would need to see the whole log. Update your question and post the whole of it.. I need to see if it is OutOfMem or NPE or what..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set the bitmap that is returned as the bitmap for the canvas. But `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)` returns an immutable bitmap. Convert this to a mutable bitmap and then set is to the canvas.

Try this:

```
Bitmap loadedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
Bitmap drawableBitmap = loadedBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

canvas = new Canvas(drawableBitmap);
paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
imageView.setImageBitmap(drawableBitmap);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks it works I was barely able to see it, it's drawing on the top right hand corner. I'm not sure why but my drawing on the picture are confined to the top left and corner of the photo.

Comment: I'll try this 

 Bitmap loadedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
             Bitmap scaledloadedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(loadedBitmap, 120, 120, false);
             Bitmap drawableBitmap = scaledloadedBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);